# Can't Open files from a directory in python

Tags: python, ioerror

I have written a small module that first finds all the files in the directory, and merge them.
But, I'm having the problem with opening these files from a directory.
I made sure that my files and directory names are correct, and files are actually in the directory.

Below is the code..

```
 seqdir = "results"
 outfile = "test.txt"

 for filename in os.listdir(seqdir):
     in_file = open(filename,'r')
```

Below is the error..

```
     in_file = open(filename,'r')     
     IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hen1-1-rep1.txt'
```

Comment: Problem might be that you're not using absolute paths -- see isedev's just-posted answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

listdir returns just the file names: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir You need the fullpath to open the file. Also check to make sure it is a file before you open it. Sample code below.

```
for filename  in os.listdir(seqdir):
    fullPath = os.path.join(seqdir, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
        in_file = open(fullPath,'r')
        #do you other stuff
```

However for files it is better to open using the [with](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) keyword. It handles closing for you even when there are exceptions. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects for details and an example